# Angularjs input to increase a number of element

Tags: angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple input to enter a number.

When I enter a number, I want this number of buttons created directly below.

Example : I type in "8" in the input.
8 buttons are created below

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Number of steps" ng-model="nbrOfSteps">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="itemNumber" ng-change="generateButtons()">
<div>
  <button ng-repeat="button in list track by $index">button#{{$index}}</button>
</div>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.generateButtons = function(){
   $scope.list = [];
    for(i=0;i<$scope.itemNumber;i++){
        $scope.list.push("");
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/oqopaw5r/

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly ! Do you know how I can have a default value ? When I land on the page, I would like to see already 2 buttons for example

Comment: use `ng-init="itemNumber=1;generateButtons()"` in your DOM